# How does java distinguish between java and resources directories?

Tags: java, maven

When I create a Maven project in eclipse, I see two nested directories created: src/main/java and src/main/resources. I understand that Maven is designed for src/main/resources to be used for non-code files, but the question is:

How does java know to look in the resources folder but not the java folder for arbitrary file lookups with `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("...")`? I can put a file in the java directory and it does not get found. Is there something more than just the `-classpath` being used to indicate where files would be located? It would seem there must be, otherwise I could put arbitrary files in either java or resources.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. It's about how Maven builds and packages the project. Look at Maven documentation, and also look at content of generated .jar file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question about how Maven works, not about how Java find files, but I'll cover that a bit too.

Java's `ClassLoader` finds classes and resources using the CLASSPATH, which for deployed code is usually a set of `.jar` files. The class loader searches the `.jar` files, in the order listed on the classpath, until the class/resource is found.

Maven's default setup of having source files in `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources` is purely a [Maven thing](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), and has nothing to do with Java's class/resource loading.

During a build, Maven will compile `.java` source files found in `src/main/java`, and place the compiled `.class` files in `target/classes`. It will then package the `.class` files together with all files found in `src/main/resources` into the `.jar` file.

The resultant `.jar` file has all the `.class` files and resource files together, and that's where Java will find them.

Note that non-`.java` files in the `src/main/java` are ignored by the Maven build process.

If you do a Maven build and **look at the files**, you'll see all this for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Java loads resources from the “environment”, in many cases it uses all jars in Classpath to retrieve the resource. Resource loading in java is called location independent because it is not relevant where your code is running, it just needs correct environment to find the resources.

Given all jars and paths in Classpath, java will search relatively to each tone to find the resource you specified. You specify resources using resource names.

**ClassLoader** and **Class** apply resource names differently

The methods in ClassLoader use the given String as the name of the
resource without applying any absolute/relative transformation (cf. the
methods in Class). The name should not have a leading “/”.
Read more from http://www.thinkplexx.com/learn/howto/java/system/java-resource-loading-explained-absolute-and-relative-names-difference-between-classloader-and-class-resource-loading

> It would seem there must be, otherwise I could put arbitrary files in
>   either java or resources.

Yes, you can put any where in a project, but you should read carefully structure of maven standard directory layout to put files following rule:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html